# Ember Data for Non Standard Rest Calls

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Very new to ember sorry if any dumbness, I was trying to create a custom adapter and serializer in ember, by extending DS.RESTadapter,and Rest serializer , I was successful in getting the response and massage the data to suit the model needs, but I was not able to get the model values in the template using model property, however i got a way to get the values , request you to kindly help me with the right way

**Model**

```
App.Weather = DS.Model.extend({
    name   : DS.attr('string'),
    temperature  : DS.attr('string'),
    humidity : DS.attr('string'),
    description : DS.attr('string'),
});
```

**Adapter**

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

    buildURL: function(item) {
        return "http://website/weather?q=" + item['q']+ "&appid="+item['appid'];
    },

    findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
        return this.ajax(this.buildURL(query), 'GET');
    }
});
```

Serializer

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

    extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
        var weathers = [{
            id: 1 // Id hard coded
        }];


        weathers[0]["name"]=payload["name"];
        weathers[0]["temperature"]=payload["main"]["temp"];
        weathers[0]["humidity"]=payload["main"]["humidity"];
        weathers[0]["description"]=payload["weather"][0]["description"];
        weathers[0]["type"]=payload["weather"][0]["main"];

        payload = { weathers: weathers };

        return this._super(store, type, payload);
    }
});
```

**Route**

```
App.WeatherIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) { 
        //debugger;
       return this.store.find('weather',{q:"London", `enter code here`appid:"b552aef423b1cf586b62d1ab1d4ef216"});

    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('default');
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {

        **controller.set('model', model.content[0]);**
    }
})
```

As Above I am getting all the values under model.Content Array.

Not understanding y i would have to do model.content instead of just model. and why would it nest itself this way.

I am using a older version of ember
ember-1.1.2.js

Comment: You don't need to set model property in setupController hook. since this will be automatically set by parent Controller. Ensure you should call this._super(..arguments)

Comment: For information on nested adapters, see: Slides (http://www.slideshare.net/RyanMHarrison/nest-v-flat-with-emberdata) and/or Video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjAMSjFPLW8)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to learn Ember, do not use version for which you cannot find documentation. If you can't use versions 2.x then download 1.13.

The easiest way, how to handle non-standard REST responses is to modify normalize() method [http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize] which should take any response you have and create JSON in a format that is required by your serializer.